# iPhone- How to save the view controller object itself?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, savestate

I want to save the state of my view controller. I searched and found that I should save the state by saving state variables.

But I am interested in saving the view controller object itself. Is there any way to save the view controller object itself so that when I restart the application I see the same view state too on which I was before closing the app. Otherwise I have to reach that state myself and that will not solve the purpose fully as somethings like (the admob ad which was displayed) could not be restored.

If I am wrong at some place or miss something please guide me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into implementing NSCoding in all the classes you want to persist.  If you properly implement that and then encode your object graph at a root node (like a tab bar controller or a nav bar controller) with something like NSKeyedArchiver/NSKeyedUnarchiver when your app terminates and starts up, you can save and restore the state of a view controller easily.  UIViewController and UIView implement it by default, so all you need to do is override the encodeWithCoder: and decodeWithCoder: methods, call super, and save the state variables you need.