# How to save view or controller object so that can we retrieve in the same state.

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, interface-builder

I’m working on a **iOS(7)** app that let you design **iPhone** screen in **iPhone itself** like the way `interface builder` does.
In this app I have canvas screen where user will be able to drag & drop multiple component like **buttons, labels, text fields, nav bar, tab bar etc**.

for example screen could be like this

[image]

Now on exit on this screen I want to save the state of this screen with all the components so that I can retrieve it and able to show it back to user with all components with same frame and properties.

One Idea I had, that is to archive whole view object and save it and when user demand that screen back I’ll unarchive that view and assign it back to the controller.
but I think this is not a good approach to do this, if any one have better idea for the same please let me know. thanks in advance.

Comment: try staterestorization protocols of viewcontroller and appdelegate for saving the state of the object.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768903/iphone-how-to-save-the-view-controller-object-itself use this

Comment: @Suryakant I am having a similar problem as urs, how did u managed to solve it?

Comment: @WaelShowair not exactly remember since it was a 3 year old affair now, I used `NSArchiver` and `NSKeyedArchiver` to store object as it is. Now you have `NSKeyedArchiver` and `NSKeyedUnarchiver` as well. give a shot to these class.